# Why can't I use a bit field as a boolean expression in a SQL case statement?

Tags: sql, boolean, case, bit

I want to select something conditionally based on whether a bit field is true or false. This was the syntax that I originally tried:

```
CASE WHEN isSoon THEN 'Soon' ELSE 'Not so soon' END As HowSoon
```

This makes sense to me since what follows the "WHEN" has to be a boolean expression, which `isSoon` is, as it's a bit field. However, this didn't work. What I had to do in the end was:

```
CASE WHEN isSoon = 1 THEN 'Soon' ELSE 'Not so soon' END As HowSoon
```

This seems redundant to me... It's like writing `if(isSoon == True)` in a programming language instead of the more intuitive `if(isSoon)` and goes against the grain. Why is SQL set up like this? Is it because bit fields aren't truly boolean?

Comment: Can you also say what database provider you're using? MySQL doesn't seem to have a problem with that.

Comment: This bugs me too, but sql isnt set up that way. Just in the same way that you cannot use a calculation when you pass a parameter to a SP (for ex you cannot do `exec ListPermissionsByUser @DomainName + '\' + @UserName`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the bit datatype **is not a boolean type**, it's a datatype used to optimize the bit storage.

The fact that the string "true" and "false" can be converted to a bit can be misleading, however, quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) , a bit is *"An integer data type that can take a value of 1, 0, or NULL."*

Comment: This does not seem to answer the WHY of it.  Yeah it is a 1, 0 or null.  But that is just a nullable boolean (assuming the column allows nulls).  WHY did the SQL folks decide to treat it like a `supersmallint` rather than as the bool that it represents and is used as 99.9999% of the time.

Comment: @Vaccano: It is answer actually. Data type with 3 possible states (nullable bool - bit in SQL case) is very different from data type with 2 possible states (bool)